# Is it possible to make this type of layout?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and I was wondering if is it possible to make this kind of layout?

[image]

Comment: These are just tabs with a viewpager (the content area) and a tablayout (those three tabs in there). Create a new Tabbed activity and see yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
The view is tabs, and to create it you use a combination of two views, fragments and an adapter 
Views:

```
TabLayout
ViewPager
```

Read about fragment adapter and tabs

Here's a good tutorial
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

If you're looking for an easy solution you can you the library I created it offer multiple customization options and it's really easy to use
https://github.com/gilgoldzweig/EasyTabs